# Simple Circle Geometry Question [homework]

Tags: geometry

Diameter EF of a circle centre A is extended to B and from B a line is drawn tangent to the circle at C. CD is drawn perpendicular with D on EF.

Prove that $BE\cdot BF  - DE\cdot DF=BD^2$

Struggling with this one. Any help is appreciated.

[image: Figure]

Comment: This is not the place where people do your homework. If you want help solving a problem, write up what you have done so far and ask more thoughtful. You will find that people are more responsive when you put in effort to your questions.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Note that the followings are true$$BC^2=BD^2+CD^2\qquad \text{(Pythagorean theorem)}\\BC^2=BE\cdot BF\\CD^2=AC^2-AD^2=AF^2-AD^2$$

Comment: I don't understand how you got 

$BC^2=BE\cdot BF$

and

$CD^2=AC^2−AD^2=AF^2−AD^2$

Comment: BC^2=BE.BF is a theorem in geometry (since triangles BEC and BCF are similar) and AC and AF are both radius of the circle

Answer (score 0):

HINT

It is to use similar triangles and Pythogaras thm. Let $C'$ be reflected on circle about $AB$.

In a Circle the product of segments is equal. In this special case perpendicular segments are for internal point $D$ the *power* of circle

$$ DC\cdot DC'=DC^2= DE\cdot DF $$

and for external point $B$ the power is

$$ BD\cdot BE= BC^2. $$